# Conversion of character object into HTML

Tags: html, css, r, xml

I am looking for a solution to convert a character object into an HTML object:

```
url <- "www.somewebsite.com"
page<- POST(url=url,encode="raw")
```

Now I am missing the conversion part(`page` is either character or response object depending on the `encoding`), so that I can take benefit of HTML dedicated functions, e.g.:

```
offer_title<-page %>% 
html_nodes(".offer-item-title")%>%
html_text()
```

This question may be considered as opposite to this [thread: "How to convert an HTML R object to character?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058279/how-to-convert-an-html-r-object-to-character)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058279/how-to-convert-an-html-r-object-to-character

Comment: From the rvest library use `page<-read_html(url)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping out. In fact there was similar thread to what my question refered to: errors caused by invalid useage of rvest package objects. If someone encouters in the future similar problem, then the following link might shed a little bit of light: [link][Rvest scraping errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320977/rvest-scraping-errors)